# commands with variable adds horizontal spacing in text

Tags: macros, color, white-space

I am using the following command to create two version of an article, one 
where changes with respect to the first version are showed in blue 
and a second one that is supposed to be the final version (regular font color). Here is my command:

```
\newcommand{\rev}[1]{
  \iflogvar
    \color{blue}{#1}
  \else
    {#1}
  \fi
}
```

However, it appears that using this command add some horizontal spacing as shown by the images below:

Image 1: \rev{Additionally, ....} with logvar set to true:

[image]

Image 2: \rev{Additionally, ....} with logvar set to false

[image]:

Image 3: Additionally, .... without the command:

[image]

I saw in some posts that the command \color{}{} adds vertical spacing and
I am not sure if this is related to \color or to the if clause of the command. 
Any thoughts on this one?

Many thanks,

Comment: I don't think the whitespace before "Additionally" is due to the `\color` command, it's just there for justification. Something else changes to cause the first line of your Image 3 to start with "bound". Not saying it isn't a `\color`, but your samples don't show it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three spourious spaces in your macro, produced by the line breaks. One of them is before the text. They can be eliminated by adding a comment sign (`%`) at the end of the line.

```
\newcommand{\rev}[1]{% <-- space removed
  \iflogvar
    \color{blue}{#1}% <-- space removed
  \else
    {#1}% <-- space removed
  \fi
}
```

Untested due to lack of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).